# Finding out where AJAX calls addresses (Radio web app)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

http://liveradio.mediacorp.sg/meradio/public/xinmsn/player/onlineplayer.php?station=905fm

I'm trying to find out where the calls of the AJAX for this radio web app goes to.
I want to be able to retrieve the artist, song name, picture in order to create a simple app instead of using the web browser.

I've found out there are events assigned to $jw player object but i can't find out how (or where) to actually extract where they get the data (artist,song name ect) from to parse.

vendor_scripts.compile.min.js : Seems to be the one assigning all the api calls to the player.

RADIOactive-1.2.18.min.js : Seems to be the api functions to retrieve the data

main.min.js : player is ready function and javascript to change the artist,song name on the html? (not very sure on that)

I've tried using firebug to find where the calls are being made to but there is no log when the song artist and name is changed.

As for the album picture, there is a GET request logged but it's the parsed data not the actually address where they get the data from.

EG: http://radio.c0m/?picture=http://abc.c0m/a.jpg which is static.

I would want the dynamic address where http://abc.c0m/a.jpg is retrieved from.

EG: http://radio.com/currentsongalbum -> which data would be "abc.c0m/a.jpg"

Thanks!

Comment: Use your developer tools. It will show you ever AJAX call being made, as well as the response.

Comment: I've tried that but I can't find it. I've been using firebug too but there isn't any call logged when the song artist, name is changed.

Comment: In Chrome Developer Tools, add an XHR Breakpoint, and set it to break when the URL contains `/`.

Comment: In chromedev tools, you may want to check websockets as well as just xhr